# Limit RDP from public Ip for specific user

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp

i am using windows server 2008, i have some users associated with rdp group. and i have allowed these users to take remote desktop on server. my server ip 10.0.0.2 subnet is 10.0.0.0/24 my public IP is 121.22.22.13 . i have opened rdp port on my router to take remote desktop connection on server. now i want that only administrator account can take login for public IP. and other users can take login by 10.0.0.2 ip only. i am beginner on 2k8 . I need someone experts guidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now i want that only administrator account can take login for public
>   IP. and other users can take login by 10.0.0.2 ip only

This isn't possible.  You can't limit RDP access this way.

You really shouldn't allow straight RDP to a public IP either IMO.  Setup a simple VPN for only the administrator account instead if your issue is accessing the server from external.